# Max frequency 1d array in a 2d numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, mode

I've a 2d numpy array:

```
array([[21, 17, 11],
   [230, 231, 232],
   [21, 17, 11]], dtype=uint8)
```

I want to find the 1d array which is more frequent. For the above 2d array it is:
[21, 17, 11]. It is something like mode in stats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with its optional arg `return_counts` to get the counts for each unique row and finally get the `argmax()` to choose the one with the max count -

```
# a is input array
unq, count = np.unique(a, axis=0, return_counts=True)
out = unq[count.argmax()]
```

For `uint8` type data, we can also convert to `1D` by reducing each row to a scalar each and then use `np.unique` -

```
s = 256**np.arange(a.shape[-1])
_, idx, count = np.unique(a.dot(s), return_index=True, return_counts=True)
out = a[idx[count.argmax()]]
```

If we are working with color images that are `3D` (the last axis being the color channel) and want to get the most dominant color, we need to reshape with `a.reshape(-1,a.shape[-1])` and then feed it to the proposed methods.

Comment: Isn't `np.tensordot(a, s, axes = ((-1), (0)))` just `np.tensordot(a, s, 1)`?

Comment: @DanielF True! Thanks for reminding about that functionality! Or we could simply use `np.dot`. Edited that part.

Comment: Also your second solution only works for `a.shape[-1]` less than or equal to 3.  Or 7 if you do `256 ** np.arange(8, dtype = 'int64')`.  Otherwise you overflow.